# How to categorize closing a valid question dealing with using pirated software?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, flags

For what reason should I select for closing this question? https://superuser.com/questions/10673/activate-windows-7-ultimate-with-home-premium-key It deals with using a leaked copy of windows 7 and I did not think that was ever appropriate. I voted to close, but marked reason as "subjective and argumentative". It is a valid question, and nothing else seem to fit. Is this an appropriate category from the official reason list for closure?

Comment: How about providing us with a list of the different possible close reasons? I don't have enough rep to know what the different reasons are.

Comment: You could always just flag it for mod attention, which is probably more appropriate in this case.

Comment: Yah, I just have 3k vote to close rights on SU. I suppose I could flag a mod, but they will have to state a reason why to delete it though and be presented with the same list I believe. Someone correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I flagged it for mod attention with the reason: It's about running illegal software.

Comment: Hey Troggy, welcome to the 3K+ crowd! I see you already started closing :)

Comment: @Troggy - ♦ moderators don't need to give a reason to delete something; if we **close** it we do, but delete just makes it go away.

Comment: @Marc Yah I meant to say "reason why to close it" and not delete in my previous comment. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: If questions about pirating software are on-topic, so why that one was closed? A contradiction in title in my opinion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just flag for mod attention to be deleted.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I find questions like that very offensive (somebody's trying to get me to do something illegal), and I'd vote to close on "blatantly offensive".  I'd also flag the question.   Sometimes there's no such thing as overkill.

Answer (score 2):

I closed the question and deleted it immediately after. It is safer to just let it go away quietly I believe.

As Marc already pointed out, flag it for moderator attention and we will act upon it. Flame throwers work wonders.

Comment: It is good to see you using your newly appointed power well.